# How to make two identical panels in KDE plasma?

Tags: kde, plasma5

I have a dual monitor setup on my laptop with KDE Plasma 5. I want the panel to be identical on both displays without manually changing both every time I want to change something. So for example, if I pin a new app to the task bar on monitor (A) I want to have that change apply to monitor (B) as well. Is there a way to achieve this behavior? (I do not want to mirror the screen)